# Nomenclature for app that moves / resizes windows

Tags: windows

MacOS has a rectangle: an app that Move and resize windows: https://rectangleapp.com/

I would like to know the class of applications that move and resize windows, so that I can Google versions for MS-Windows.   Ideally, an app similar to Windows is available through github.

Comment: Window manager - Not sure of a third party app, but windows has this built in. Use Win+arrow key to snap a window. If you have Windows 11, then you can press Win+Z and then choose a bunch of "snap layouts".  = https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241#WindowsVersion=Windows_11

Answer (score 1):

I believe the vernacular terms are "window managers" or "file explorers".  The former deals with window sizing, positioning, and placement controls, etc., while the latter deals with directory navigation and file management.

Comment: @gatorback For Windows OS, [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) — developed by Microsoft — is comprised of various useful tools compiled into a single application, of which FancyZones would fit the function you are seeking.